# Node.js - Express special characters in routes (/campañas)

Tags: node.js, express, routes, character

I have a problem trying to set a route in Node JS with Express framework.

My route is this one:

```
app.get('/campaña/nueva', sms.nueva);
```

But i cant get it to work, because of the evil "Ñ" (it works with an "N" tho)

I used codeigniter for a while, and you can set what characters you want to enable or disable 
Do you guys knows of any workarround or way to enable it in node?

Comment: You could URI encode the ñ into %C3%B1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you'll need to handle both a URL-encoded and perhaps a UTF-8 (and possibly Latin-1 also) variant. Check the following:

1. How are your clients (browsers) sending the URL?

   - [URL encoded](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/accentedcharacters.htm) as `%C3%B1` ?

     - chrome and firefox send the `%C3%B1` encoding
     - I would presume this is the dominant and compliant behavior
   - Unicode ?

     - I tested with `curl` and it looks to send a single character which I presume is just whatever encoding it got from my terminal, which is probably UTF-8.
2. Based on that, try adjusting your route. You could use a regex or an explicit list

.

```
app.get('/campaña/nueva', sms.nueva)
app.get('/campa%c3%b1a/nueva', sms.nueva)
//Or for convenience if you like
app.get('/' + encodeURIComponent('campaña') + '/nueva', sms.nueva)
```

My guess is ultimately most browsers are going to send the URL-encoded versions, so you can probably get by with just that last version.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the same problem with `$` in my route. URL encoded character doesn't work in my case, but escaped one works.

So I ended up with

```
app.get('/\\$myRoute', function (req, res) {

}
```